# C# winforms application: event handler when returning (focus) from an external application

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, focus

I have a winforms application which has to perform an action every time when returning from an **external** application (i.e. focus has been lost from my application, alt-tabbing to another program and then back).

Is there an application event handler for this?

I have looked into the activate and deactive handlers of a Form, but these handlers are also fired when my form receives focus back from itself (when closing a messagebox or closing a subform).

Comment: what if you just had a bool flag and set it after the first occurence, and only perform the action if it isnt set?

Comment: yes, that is what my current solution is, I was just wondering whether such an event existed.

Comment: Unfortunately WinForms does not have the `Application.Activated` event. It's possible to implement one by trapping the `WM_ACTIVATEAPP` message, which will be sent to each open `Form` once whenever the application is activated or deactivated.

Comment: No, just wanted to make sure you received the compliment. Also mentioned [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192469/why-was-my-suggested-edit-rejected-repeatedly/192570#192570). Thanks for the edit ;-) (Cleaning up my comments; will remove this one soon as well.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows sends the [`WM_ACTIVATEAPP` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632614.aspx) to a window when it is being activated, and when it is being deactivated. So this is what you want to handle, specifically when `wParam` is `TRUE` (indicating activation).

WinForms does not wrap this as an event (at least not that I'm aware of), so you'll need to add the code to your form's window procedure manually:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    // other code

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int WM_ACTIVATEAPP = 0x001C;
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_ACTIVATEAPP:
            {
                if (m.WParam.ToInt32() != 0)
                {
                    // Your application's window is being activated, so
                    // do whatever it is you want. Or raise an event.
                    ...
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);  // proceed with default processing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Zurb. [Your suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2678339) was basicaly spot on, but erroneously rejected by the three reviewers. I've made the edits myself. I had my braces misplaced, and I'd forgotten that you can't implicitly compare IntPtr to bool in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I would just set a bool value, you could lock the read/write part to make sure that the action is only called once.

Comment: What you mean by lock? lock statement?

Comment: There's really no need to synchronize access if you only access the boolean variable from the UI thread, which seems to be the case here.

Comment: @Servy boolean read/write is atomic right? Do we really require lock when multiple thread is accessing? Apart from optimization this is not required I think. am I right?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel You would need to use `volatile` at the very least, but yes, it is an atomic read/write.  It depends on the specifics of how it's used though, if both a read and a write need to be performed atomically, then synchronization *does* need to occur.  As I said, though, all of this code is likely to be in the UI thread, so it will already be synchronized.